# Template member functions with trailing return type, giving errors even if unused

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, member-functions, trailing-return-type

I understand that template member functions are only generated if used. This is convenient if not all used types support such a function. However, this does not appear to work for functions with trailing return type specification. Below is a small experiment:

```
// helper function for case A workaround
template <typename A, typename T>
auto F(T&& x)
-> decltype(x.template f <A>())
    { return x.template f <A>(); }

// helper function for case B workaround
template <typename A, typename T>
auto G(T&& x)
-> decltype(x.g())
    { return x.g(); }

template <typename T>
struct S
{
    // case A: not ok in GCC + Clang
    template <typename A>
    auto f1()
    -> decltype(T().template f <A>())
        { return T().template f <A>(); }

    // case A workaround: ok in Clang + GCC
    template <typename A>
    auto f2()
    -> decltype(F <A>(T()))
        { return F <A>(T()); }

    // case B: ok in GCC, not ok in Clang
    template <typename A>
    auto g1()
    -> decltype(T().g())
        { return T().g(); }

    // case B workaround: ok in GCC + Clang
    template <typename A>
    auto g2()
    -> decltype(G <A>(T()))
        { return G <A>(T()); }
};
```

Please keep in mind that this sample is only meant to illustrate the issue, it is not useful in anything else.

`S <T>` can be instantiated for any type `T` that has appropriate member functions `f`, `g`.

However, if I try to instantiate `S <int>`, e.g. by `S <int> s{};`, I do get errors like `type 'int' is not a structure or union`. This happens for both cases `f1`, `g1`, which attempt to call template function `f` or non-template function `g` respectively on a value of type `T` (`int` in this case). It happens even though I am not trying to call `f1` or `g1` on object `s`. However, GCC is fine with the case of `g1`; Clang is not.

A workaround for case A (template member function `f`) is to use a helper function `F`, which is what `f2` does, and works fine for both Clang and GCC. It appears to work because call `T().template f <A>()` is hidden from the declaration of `f2`, and the compiler is not looking into `F <A>(T())` when type `A` is unknown.

The same workaround for case B (non-template member function `g`) is also working for both compilers.

I would appreciate some help in finding out what is going on. Which is the correct behaviour in each case? Which compiler is correct? Is there any other workaround in general?

I am using GCC 4.8.1 and Clang 3.3.

Comment: not an answer to your question but is `x.template f <A>()` a legal c++ statement? Shouldn't it just be `x.f<A>()`

Comment: @Gasim It may be ugly, but unfortunately `template` keyword is needed. For instance `f` may be a data member, so `x.f<A` may mean a comparison.

Comment: Do you know about [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)?

Comment: g++ 4.8.1 is not fine with it, since int really has no member function `g()`

Comment: When a class template is instantiated, the declarations of its member functions are also instantiated (but not the definitions). That is, the declarations have to be valid even if the functions are not used. Of course, member function templates may contain expressions that, after substitution of *their* template arguments, are illegal. However, substitution of the class template's parameters happens as part of the class template's instantiation.

Comment: @dyp Thanks, this explains the situation. I've seen several occasions of the same situation in practice, which always seem unexpected, but I'm now trying to understand it. For instance, given expression `T().template f <A>()`, it seems pointless to attempt validation if `A` is unknown; however, substituting to `int().template f <A>()` it is evident that the expression is invalid whatever `A` may be. But it still looks pointless and wasteful if this function is never used.

Comment: @Constructor I can't see how `enable_if` would help - anything more specific?

Comment: @iavr I think the alternative to an error is to ignore the entire function template. But then, the "class is not complete": it lacks this particular function (template), and errors might *later* occur at other places that try to use that function (template).

Comment: @dyp I understand there is good reason, thanks again. My struggle besides the invalid expressions above is to keep compile times reasonable, and such 'unnecessary' validation may increase time exponentially, e.g. by recursively triggering valid but costly computations for types that will never be used. It's extremely difficult to find and resolve such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFINAE only applies to the template arguments of the function, not the one inherited from the class.

A different solution is to include copy T to a second template argument but this is nothing more than a shorter version of your workaround:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>    
struct Foo {
    template < typename T > T f() { return {}; }
};
template <typename T>
struct S {
    template <typename A, typename TT = T >
    auto f1()  -> decltype(std::declval<TT>().template f <A>()) { 
        static_assert(std::is_same<T,TT>::value, "TT must be equal to T" );
        return TT().template f <A>(); 
    }
};

int main() {
    S<Foo> a;
    a.f1<int>(); // ok

    S<int> b;
    b.f1<int>(); // not ok
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this workaround is definitely better, I'll keep it in mind (for the moment, I've bypassed the problem altogether by using additional functions that make the code more generic anyway). I've used a similar idea of introducing a dummy template argument to control an otherwise non-template default constructor by enable_if (a default constructor has no argument and no return type, so there's nowhere to put enable_if unless it becomes template).

Comment: @iavr the above results in an ill formed program with no diagnosis required: all `template` functions must have at least one specialization that is valid.